# how to get js mouse coordinates into a php insert query?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, insert, coordinates

I'm trying to create a user interface, which automatically inserts data into the database. This data should also include the mouse coordinates, since i want to create a pin at a world map at that place.

The problem is i don't know how to get the mouse coordinates into the php insert query. could sb help me please?

**PHP**

```
<body>
    <h1>Add Project to the database</h1>        
    <div class="left_column">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="//www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 620" xmlns:xlink="//www.w3.org/1999/xlink">               
            //country paths ...
        </svg>
    </div>
    <?php       
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $username = "root";
        $password = "clacs_2013";
        $hostname = "localhost"; 

        $conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
          or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
        print_r("INSERT INTO projects VALUES ('".$_POST['project_ID']."', '".$_POST['project_name']."', '".$_POST['project_desc']."', '".$_POST['leftCoord']."', '".$_POST['topCoord']."')");
        $insertProject= mysql_query("INSERT INTO projects VALUES ('".$_POST['project_ID']."', '".$_POST['project_name']."', '".$_POST['project_desc']."', '".$_POST['leftCoord']."', '".$_POST['topCoord']."');") 
                            or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db("clacs") or die(mysql_error()); 

        $retval = mysql_query( $insertProject, $conn );
        if(! $retval )
        {
          die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
        mysql_close($conn);
        }
        else
        {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
        project ID: <input type="text" name="project_ID"><br/>
        project name: <input type="text" name="project_name"><br/>
        project description: <input type="text" name="project_desc"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$(".country").click(function(e) {   
    $("form").css("display", "block");

    var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

    var leftCoord = Math.round( (e.clientX - offset_l) );
    var topCoord = Math.round( (e.clientY - offset_t) );

});         
});
```

Comment: Sure you can use Javascript for this; but if you're submitting a form anyway, you could consider using `<input type="image" ...>` (which submits the coordinates of the mouse click).

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is a server side language, you can't directly access these properties that run on the client side.

However you can create two hidden inputs into your form that will hold the mouse coordinates (x and y) and make a JavaScript code that will watch the mouse move and update this fields regularly.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('#input_x').val(e.pageX)
    $('#input_y').val(e.pageY)
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/av4wM/2/

Comment: thank you sooo much. i was trying to figure that out for hours already!

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @Guilherme Sehn 's solution with your code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    project ID: <input type="text" name="project_ID"><br/>
    project name: <input type="text" name="project_name"><br/>
    project description: <input type="text" name="project_desc"><br/>
    <input type="hidden" id="topCoord" name="topCoord">
    <input type="hidden" id="leftCoord" name="leftCoord">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$(".country").click(function(e) {   
    $("form").css("display", "block");

    var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

    var leftCoord = Math.round( (e.clientX - offset_l) );
    var topCoord = Math.round( (e.clientY - offset_t) );

    $('#topCoord').val(topCoord);
    $('#leftCoord').val(leftCoord);
});         
});
```

Obviously that can be simplified